# Pointer arithmetic: huffman tree traversal

Tags: c, pointers, tree, huffman-code

I am confused in pointer arithmetic, I want to make a tree traversal function, but I am not quite sure about pointer arithmetic to get distant nodes in the tree. It will be a lot more clear when seen in the code, so here it is.

```
node **root = huffman_tree(probabilities); // I can only return that as a double ptr
```

Now if I want data from my root node:

```
printf("%lf", (*root)->data);
```

If I want data from roots children:

```
printf("%lf", (*root)->left->data); // or (*root)->right->data
```

But what if I want to go further in depth search, I dont know how to reach those nodes?

```
printf("%lf", (*root)->left->left->data); // thats not working
```

Also, for tree traversal, this is not working: the program crashes.

```
node **root = huffman_tree(probabailities);
preorder(*root);

void preorder(node *n){
if(n == NULL) return;
printf("%lf", n->data);
preorder(n->left);
preorder(n->right);
```

}

For the above examples, the program crashes.

**Update 1:**

It seems like huffman_tree() is indeed returning a tree with corrupted nodes, I must be doing memory allocation for them incorrectly.

The function is passed an array of probabilities, and then obtains steps as it follows:

1) creates nodes with given probabilities (n probabilities --> n new nodes) [works fine]

2) finds the two nodes with lowest probabilities [works fine]
3) creates a new node which is the parent of the two lowest probabilities nodes

4) assign a new node probability equal to the sum of it's children's probabilities

5) repeat from step 2) until there is only one parentless node left

```
node **huffman_tree(double *probabs){


int num_of_nodes = NUM_OF_SYMBOLS;
int num = NUM_OF_SYMBOLS;

// 1) create nodes for given probabilities
node *leafs = (node*) malloc(num_of_nodes*sizeof(node));
int i;
for(i=0; i<num_of_nodes; i+=1){
    node *n = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->probab = *(probabs + i);
    n->symbol = *(SYMBOLS + i);
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    *(leafs+i) = *n;
    //free(n);
}

node **root;

while(num_of_nodes > 1){

    // 2) Find the two nodes with lowest probabilities
    node *two_mins =(node *)malloc(2*sizeof(node));
    two_mins = find_two_mins(leafs, num_of_nodes);
    node min_n1 = two_mins[0];
    node min_n2 = two_mins[1];


    // 3) Create a parent node with probability equals to sum of its children probabilities
            // add a parent node to leafs
    node *new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->probab = min_n1.probab + min_n2.probab;
    new_node->left = &min_n1;
    new_node->right = &min_n2;

    leafs = add_node(leafs, new_node, num);
    num += 1;
    leafs = remove_node(leafs, &min_n1, num);
    num -= 1;
    leafs = remove_node(leafs, &min_n2, num);
    num -= 1;

    num_of_nodes -= 1;

    root = &new_node;
}

return root;
```

Function add_node() [seems to be working fine]

```
node *add_node(node *nodes, node *n, int num){
nodes = realloc(nodes, (num+1)*sizeof(node));
nodes[num] = *n;
return nodes;
```

Function remove_node() [seems to be working fine]

```
node *remove_node(node *nodes, node *n, int num){
int i;
int index = 0;
for(i=0; i<num; i+=1){
    if(nodes_are_equal(nodes[i], *n)) index = i;
}

for(i=index; i<num-1; i+=1){
    nodes[i] = nodes[i+1];
}

nodes = realloc(nodes, (num-1)*sizeof(node));

return nodes;
```

**Update 2**

I have changed some things in huffman_tree() function.

Function find_two_mins() no longer exists, but it is replaced with two calls of another function find_min(), which finds only one minimum node at a time. Also, this function takes pointer to the dynamically allocated node, and after minimum value is found, returns it back.

```
    node *root;

while(num_of_nodes > 1){

    // 2) Find two min nodes
    node *min_n1= (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node*min_n2= (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    *min_n1= *find_min(leafs, num, min_n1);
    leafs = remove_node(leafs, min_n1, num);
    num -= 1;

    *min_n2= *find_min(leafs, num, min_n2);
    leafs = remove_node(leafs, min_n2, num);
    num -= 1;

    printf("\nTwo Min Nodes:  %lf\t%lf", min_n1->probab, min_n2->probab);
    printf("\nSum Of All: %lf", s);


    // 3) Create parent node of two min nodes

    node *new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->probab= min_n1->probab+ min_n2->probab;
    new_node->left = min_n1;
    new_node->right = min_n2;

    leafs = add_node(leafs, new_node, num);
    num += 1;

    free(min_n1);
    free(min_n2);

    num_of_nodes -= 1;

    root = new_node;

    printf("root=%p\n", root);
    printf("*root=%p\n", *root);
}

return root;
```

And here is the find_min() function:

```
node *find_min(node *nodes, int num, node *min_node){

double min_probab = nodes[0].probab;
*min_node= nodes[0];

int i;
for(i=0; i<num; i+=1){
    if(nodes[i].probab< min_probab){
        min_probab = nodes[i].probab;
        *min_node = nodes[i];
    }
}

return min_node;
```

It seems like the problem is something about this output:

```
        printf("root=%p\n", root);
    printf("*root=%p\n", *root);
```

Since it outputs "root = 003A17F0" and "*root = 00000000"

Also, I am providing a screenshot of how the program runs, where root values at any point can be seen.
[image: how it runs]

Comment: you need to use `->` instead of `-`

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: What do you mean by "thats not working".  What is it doing?  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: are you sure that there is a node ?

Comment: Should be `if(n == NULL) return`

Comment: Well, the preorder function is not working at all, even for the 1st node. I am sure... It was a typo, Martin, fixed.
It just crashes... And I am completely sure that root has its data, and roots children have data (1st two lines of code here give that data, but not preorder function...)

Comment: It's very hard for us to get an idea of what the real problem is with lots of typos in the code.

Comment: There are no more typos, you can be sure.

Comment: Can you confirm that `huffman_tree` is returning a valid pointer?  Try putting `printf("root=%p", root);` and `printf("*root=%p", *root);` immediately after the `huffman_tree` call.

Comment: It outputs:
root = 0028FE74
*root = 003735B8

Comment: Can you post a [short, self-contained, complete, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem?  What does the code for the `huffman_tree()` function look like?  Are you by any chance returning a pointer to a stack-allocated node?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the extra info you've provided.

Answer (score 3):

`(*root)->left->left->data` is the correct way of accessing grand-child nodes, as long as the child is not null, and assuming your node looks something like:

```
struct node
{
    double data;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
}
```

Without seeing the full code, it's hard to be sure what's going on here.  Your null check in preorder looks good, so I suspect you must be somehow corrupting one of your nodes, and getting an invalid (but non-NULL) pointer in there.

Putting the following immediately after the null check in preorder should make the problem more obvious:

```
printf("processing node %p", n); fflush(stdout);
printf("  left=%p\n", n->left); fflush(stdout);
printf("  right=%p\n", n->right); fflush(stdout);
```

You're looking for pointers that don't "look like" the others, particularly just before it crashes.

The most likely causes for problems are within huffman_tree itself.  I'd suspect you've got something in there that's taking the address of a node from the stack rather than dynamically allocating it with malloc.

**Edit based on additional information supplied in your "answer":**

Your problem is probably in your `find_two_mins` function.  The following code

```
node *two_mins =(node *)malloc(2*sizeof(node));
two_mins = find_two_mins(leafs, num_of_nodes);
node min_n1 = two_mins[0];
node min_n2 = two_mins[1];
```

is (correctly) dynamically allocating the memory for the nodes, but then you are throwing the pointer to that dynamic memory away and replacing it with the result of `find_two_mins`.

You've also got some other memory leaks around the place I think (although it's not causing your problem).  Within the initial loop,

```
node *n = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
```

that doesn't get freed.  You're copying that struct into the correctly allocated `leafs` array, so just make that a `node n;`.

I haven't looked in detail any further than that, so there might be more problems, but let me know where that gets you.